# how to input date yyyy/mm/dd in angular 2

Tags: angular

[This is my model in API database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg0wn.png)
[image]

This is my `data-accessor-value.ts`

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

export const DATE_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateValueAccessor),
  multi: true
};

@Directive({
  selector: '[useValueAsDate]',
  providers: [DATE_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class DateValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.valueAsDate']) onChange = (_: any) => { };
  @HostListener('blur', []) onTouched = () => { };

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer, private _elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  writeValue(value: Date): void {
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'valueAsDate', value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'disabled', isDisabled);
  }
}
```

This is my component html input date:

```
<input formControlName="dueDate" type="date" class="form-control" useValueAsDate>
```

I follow the tutorial at https://blog.johanneshoppe.de/2016/10/angular-2-how-to-use-date-input-controls-with-angular-forms/

I want make the input date like my models in API database, you can look in my model above.

My problem is that I cannot input the date format `YYYY-MM-DD`, the error is like this:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPurX.png)
[image]

Comment: you want date like YYYY-MM-DD or yyyy/mm/dd in in API it is YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: Don't think that error has to do with your date formatting, take a closer look at the URL the error where it's trying to post.

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD sorry

Comment: this is my post function in myservices.ts   createWorkOrder(workorder: WorkOrder): Observable<number> {
    let cpHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: cpHeaders });
    console.log(this.dataURL, workorder, options);
    return this.http.post(this.dataURL, workorder, options)
      .map(success => success.status)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [angular datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples) and here simple way by using jQuery

```js
$( ".form-control" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input formControlName="dueDate" type="text" class="form-control" useValueAsDate>
```

Comment: i got error like this, "'datepicker' does not exist on type 'JQuery'."

Comment: You need to import jqery plugging in index.html in main page add it in head tag